# owl carousel ignoring options when called in function

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

i have following code:

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: false,
    center: true,
    loop: true,
    nav: false,
    dots: false,
    items: 1,
    stagePadding: 140,
    callbacks: true
    });
}
```

which works fine - as expected. But when i try to do something like this:

```
var onResize = function() {
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        autoplay: false,
        center: true,
        loop: true,
        nav: false,
        dots: false,
        items: 1,
        stagePadding: 140,
        });
    }

$(window).resize(function() {
    onResize();
});
```

then it just ignores the options. Dots are visible etc. Everything looks like it is with default options. Can somebody please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the point of doing the same in the resize handler as initially? Do you know that this function may execute sever time per second? What about 'autoWidth'? Would that now work? https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autowidth.html

Comment: i only want carousel for some resolutions. i will debounce it. this is just example. when i call it inside some function it ignores my options

Comment: Why don't you use CSS media queries to just hide the carousel for the resolutions you don't need it for?

Comment: @MelissaFreeman because it is just worst way to just have two elements. I have same element that acts different when carousel is initiated and when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The resize function isn’t better! Besides, it makes no difference to your load to use media queries to show or hide. You should try it. Keep it simple.